# Is there any difference between 'represent' and 'represent for'?

Tags: vocabulary

'Marriage represents love'
'Johnny represents for single men everywhere'

When should I use 'represent', and 'represent for'?

Comment: Maybe other, more specialist users can chime in here, but I've never seen "represent for" used, particularly not in that kind of situation. I'd stick with "*represents*".

Comment: I could imagine it being the slang meaning of [*represent*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=represent). But since we don't have the context, it could also be a simple typo, or an editing mistake (like, they originally had "stands for" there or some such, then replaced the verb but forgot to nuke the preposition). At any rate, if you have to ask this question, you should not be considering *represent for* at all.

Comment: On the flip side, you could say "Johnny represented for the delegation from Istanbul". No idea why it seems to work better in the past tense than the present.

Comment: Wouldn't it be *is the representative for*?

Answer (score 3):

There is only one interpretation that I can find licensed.

This demands that 'represent' be used as an intransitive verb here; 'When should I use "represent for"?' then becomes a poor question. With this transitive usage, it is clear that the string 'represents for' is accidental (I've added commas to make the grammar clearer):

> He represents, for the average woman, the ideal husband.

RHKWebster's has this intransitive usage:

> represent v.i. 11. to protest.

So one could possibly write

> He represented for democracy

(and certainly *They protested / represented for months*).