# 'represented for' wrong usage?

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, verb-agreement

Can someone please confirm that the grammar in this video is off. It's supposedly a teaser video for a new product from a Chinese company.

https://youtube.com/watch?v=CfgviCjtvg0

Shouldn't represent be followed by a noun here? Hope you can enlighten me.

Comment: Related, [Is there any difference between 'represent' and 'represent for'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193925/is-there-any-difference-between-represent-and-represent-for)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the grammar is off for all the sentences.

It should say:

> ```
> Metal is used for energy. It represents speed.
> Metal is used for imaging. It represents recording.
> Metal is used for protection. It represents security.
> Metal is used for playing. It represents inspiration.
> ```

It's good to use periods for every sentence, I think.

The first two sentences still don't make much sense. What does energy have to do with speed? Also, "the muse" sounds awkward the way it is used, in my opinion.

Comment: Also, what should be the proper verb tense here: In the 18th century, metal 'was used' or 'is used'? Based on your response, the latter is the correct?

Comment: @Ron: In the 18th century, metal was used.